# How to deploy parse-server on EC2 instead of Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, parse-server, pm2

I know there is a way to deploy parse-server to AWS through Beanstalk. But I don't like it because Beanstalk did quite a lot of things which I don't quite understand so I decide to deploy to EC2 directly by myself. Actually it's simple. Just create a parse-server application in my EC2 home directory.

**Package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "VERBOSE=1 nodemon ./server.js --exec babel-node",
  },
```

My **mongodb** is started as a service in my EC2 instance. Everything's fine if I run the following command to start my parse-server:

> npm run server

But this process will be terminated when I close my SSH session so that I need to run my parse-server process as a service. I chose **pm2**.

I created my pm2 app like this:

> pm2 start myapp.sh

Inside myapp.sh:

> npm run server

But when I start by pm2. It seems the database is not connected. Because I can't see any data in my dashboard and there is no log generated at all.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: When you run npm is your Mongoldb running?

Comment: Yes, it's running. Finally I solved the issue by using pm2. ```pm2 start start.sh --name w4uapi --watch```